Qemu VM with native resolution in Wayland
When I'm starting a VM with SDL under Wayland the guest does not get the native display resolution but res/host_scale.
e.g. width=2560 on the host will give the VM width=1706 at a 1.5 scaling factor. I would like to have 2560 inside the VM as well.
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
...
    -vga none \
    -device virtio-vga-gl \
    -display sdl,gl=on \

I've tried setting GDK_SCALE=1, SDL_VIDEO_WAYLAND_SCALE_TO_DISPLAY={1|0} and specifying the resolution as -device virtio-vga-gl,xres=2560,yres=1500.
This happens only with Wayland (Sway), under Xorg/i3 the full display is available.

You can achieve native host resolution with spice-vdagent
spice-vdagent needs to be installed in both guest and host system.
Next step is to run spice-vdagent in both systems in terminal and then reboot guest as soon as spice-vdagent returns to prompt.
Upon next launch of guest system run spice-vdagent again and it should give you the resolution of the host without scaling applied.
Note that I've tested this with virt-manager but if you don't use virt-manager some parameters might need to be specified regarding screen resolution.

I appreciate you trying to help but I am using -display sdl and not spice nor virt-manager.
